# JavaVM Failed to load

Tags: java

I'm trying to load the "openNLP" library in RStudio and I'm getting the following error. I get a similar error when I try to install the "RWeka" package.

How do I troubleshoot this?

```
library(openNLP)
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'openNLPdata', details:
  call: .jinit()
  error: JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs returned -1

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘openNLP’
JavaVM: requested Java version ((null)) not available. Using Java at "" instead.
JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library.
```

Comment: What version of Java do you have?

Comment: It could mean that you need JVM installed for loading openNLP and you don't have it. You can download JAVA SE from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html and it comes with JVM

Comment: @DaveNewton I think that there is no java installed since in the error it mentions null

Comment: If you check https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openNLP/index.html it needs rJava (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rJava/index.html )  which needs java JDK 1.2 or higer.

Comment: OpenNLP needs a lot more than Java 1.2.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution to my issue. This is what worked for me.  Please see below:

Launch R at the command line (to test the solution):

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server: open -a RStudio
```

Now within RStudio:

```
install.packages("rJava", type = "source")
install.packages("openNLP")
require(rJava)
require(openNLP)
```

To launch RStudio from finder (El Capitan), you have to link `libjvm.dylib` to `/usr/lib`.

```
sudo ln -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /usr/local/lib
```

Comment: This worked for me. Why not clean up your answer for others?